# DIfference between IE and FF. Colors

Tags: color, css

I have a problem with my CSS code.  Buttons look differently in IE7 and FF

Here are my buttons:
[image]

Here is my code:

```
.list-common-wrapper .button-unfixed .button-unfixed-normal[disabled] .button-background, #id-chart-editor-active-event .button-unfixed .button-unfixed-normal[disabled] .button-background, .three-lists .button-unfixed .button-unfixed-normal[disabled] .button-background {
    background: url("../images/button/btn_var_bg.gif") no-repeat scroll left -120px transparent;
    color: #777777;
    cursor: default;
    text-decoration: none;
}
list.css (line 122)
.list-common-wrapper .button-unfixed .button-unfixed-normal .button-background, #id-chart-editor-active-event .button-unfixed .button-unfixed-normal .button-background, #id-profile-editor-move-attributes-buttons .button-unfixed .button-unfixed-normal .button-background {
    color: #333333;
    cursor: pointer;
}
list.css (line 132)
.button-unfixed-normal .button-background {
    background: url("../images/button/btn_var_bg.gif") no-repeat scroll left 0 transparent;
    display: block;
    padding: 2px 8px 4px 12px;
}
button.css (line 111)
Inherited froma.button-unfixed-def #
.list-common-wrapper .button-unfixed .button-unfixed-normal[disabled], #id-chart-editor-active-event .button-unfixed .button-unfixed-normal[disabled], #id-profile-editor-move-attributes-buttons .button-unfixed .button-unfixed-normal[disabled] {
    color: #777777;
    cursor: default;
    text-decoration: none;
}
list.css (line 142)
.list-common-wrapper .button-unfixed .button-unfixed-def {
    font-size: 12px;
    line-height: 130%;
}
list.css (line 163)
.button-unfixed .button-unfixed-normal {
    color: #333333;
    text-decoration: none;
}
button.css (line 104)
.button-unfixed .button-unfixed-def {
    cursor: default;
    font-size: 12px;
    line-height: 130%;
}
button.css (line 93)
a {
    color: #175DB5;
    text-decoration: underline;
}
```

It shows that the color #777777 is displayed differently in IE7 and FF (look at the arrow):

Comment: You already asked this question in SO and it would be nice if you show your working code because it could be only IE-7 issue.

Comment: couple of questions from my side how your btn_var_bg.gif looks,the given color:#777777 supposed to be the text color. and please share a url so we can see exactly what's happening

Comment: We need to see the HTML and why oh why are you a) listing line numbers and b) listing them in a seemingly random order? (Also, this is a code question...not graphic design...wrong site)

Comment: Please do not cross-post between stack exchange sites.

Answer (score 1):

Firefox is a color managed browser. Internet Explorer is not.

There's nothing you can do to force IE to be color managed. You can merely complain to Microsoft that their browser (like always) is behind the times.

You can try removing the color profile (or convert to sRGB) for the button background. The reason you're getting a mismatch is IE is not managing the image color, so it fails to match the standard hex color.

Comment: "their browser...is behind the times".  Note that he is asking about a 6 year old browser, which by definition _is_ behind the times.  Edit:  Just checked... FF didn't support color profiles until FF3, which was released 2 years after IE7.  No excuses for IE8, but the question specifically mentions IE7.

Comment: Yeah there was no mention of the FF version and it's now at 12... so.... ???? :)

Comment: "Convert to sRGB" — That won't help, as the values in the file will be destructively converted to sRGB. Colour management only works if the file contains a profile and the viewer recognises and uses the profile.